# Laravel HTML is not displaying correctly

Tags: php, html, laravel, bootstrap-4

I made a new project in Laravel where I'm attempting to edit the bootstrap HTML for the home page. Simple enough, I have experience with bootstrap.

[The default home page looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDCw0.png)

So I went ahead and deleted the columns and page content and created my own. For example, here's the very simple layout I made to test:

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 bg-primary"></div>
        <div class="col-8">Test text goes here.</div>
        <div class="col-2 bg-primary"></div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Once again, nothing fancy, It's just to demonstrate.

[But instead it just looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fh1UJ.png)

I've tried a lot of things, I've barely tampered with this project and I even deleted the old one and just made a new project thinking it was just a glitch but nope. Help?

Comment: Check console, and get the error

Comment: Ah, the console isn't giving me any errors.

Comment: Then there are no error. Even I dont see any error

Comment: There don't seem to be any errors in the second screen you've shared. Can you further elaborate on what you're trying to achieve with your code that isn't working the way you expect?

Comment: Yeah, this jsfiddle might demonstrate what this code would normally look like. Something with laravel is just causing it to only work halfway. https://jsfiddle.net/tc7dLepk/

Answer (score -1):

Okay, update, I found the solution for anyone who may be having this same issue. I was used to using Bootstrap 4 and since that's the latest version I assumed that's what it was using but I was wrong. Most likely since Lavarel uses SASS, it uses Bootstrap 3. My code was most likely not working the same because Bootstrap 3 uses some different syntax.